# Ordinary differential equations - Graphing a direction field (by CAS or hand).

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Graph a direction field (by CAS or hand). In the field graph approximate solution curves through the given point or points (x, y) by hand.

$4 yy' = -9x, (2, 2)$

My final answer comes to

$ 4\int y\:  dy = -9\int x\:dx$ = $\frac {x^2}{2c/9}+\frac{y^2}{c/2}=1 $

I need some help here as the correct answer given by text book is 
Semi-ellipse $\frac{x^2}{4} + \frac{y^2}{9} =\frac{13}{9}$

Comment: You can know the $c$ by the known value $(2,2)$, which gives $c$=26, substituting and rearranging coefficients will give your text book answer.

Comment: @MyUserIsThis: Thanks a lot i managed to get the final answer using (2, 2) as substitutes for x and y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solving the DEQ $4 yy' = -9x$ yields:

$$y(x) = \pm \dfrac{1}{2} \sqrt {c-9 x^2}$$

At the point $(2, 2)$, we get $c = 52$, so have:

$$y(x) = \pm \dfrac{1}{2} \sqrt {52-9 x^2}$$

Squaring both sides and rearranging terms yields the semi-ellipse:

$$\dfrac{x^2}{4} + \dfrac{y^2}{9} =\dfrac{13}{9}$$

Note that this was the analytical approach, but we were also asked to graph the direction field. We get:

[image]

If we compare that slope field to our solution, do you see the semi-ellipse and can you work with the slope field?

[image]

Comment: @Avinesh: You are very welcome, you did great, just do not want to leave unanswered questions, since you and the comments did just fine. Regards

Comment: Needs a TU!! (+1)

Comment: @amWhy: Thank you! :-)